# What does this error communication mean?

Tags: bugs, kernel

Few days ago, executing the command

```
Integrate[ UnitBox[(x + y)/eps - eps/3]/eps*UnitBox[(z + y)/eps]/eps*
UnitBox[(x + z)/eps]/eps, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1},
Assumptions -> eps > 0 && eps < 1/2]
```

, I obtained that communication

> Mathematica has detected an internal error:
> iCopyExpr() called on symbol.
> Please report this error as soon as possible to
> support@wolfram.com giving as many details as possible
> of the circumstances under which it occurred.

[image]

I'd like to add that the command

`Integrate[UnitBox[(x + y)/eps]/eps*UnitBox[(z + y)/eps]/eps* UnitBox[(x + z)/eps]/eps, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},  {z, -1, 1}, Assumptions -> eps > 0 && eps < 1/2]`
results in
`1/2` without any adventures and the command `Integrate[ DiracDelta[x + y]*DiracDelta[y + z]*DiracDelta[x + z], {y, -1,  1}, {x, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]` returns the input.

Of course, a report was immediately sent by me. I am able to reproduce it on a fresh kernel just now.
However, the questions remain open: what in general terms does this error mean? is it a feature of Windows 10 only?

Comment: It means what it says: there was an internal error. It's a bug. Report it to Wolfram. Nothing more can be said here. If you program in C and know what `assert()` is for, then it should be pretty clear.

Comment: It is a common programming technique to include checks for conditions that the programmer knows should be true _if everything works as expected_. If the check fails, something is not working right. This is what happened here. The message is not intended to be understood by users like you and me. It is a debugging aid for the programmers who work on the Mathematica kernel. I hope this clears it up.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thank you though I don't understand much of your explanation.  Does it occur on Windows 10 only?

Comment: In simpler terms, there are mechanism to detect bugs in Mathematica. This message means that such a bug was detected, and they're asking you to report it. The message is meant to be interpreted by the developers, not you or me. If I run this code on macOS (M 12.2.0), it just keeps running, and does not finish. I interrupted it after about one minute.

Comment: Mathematica 8.0.4 evaluates this integral as 1/2, without any trouble. It would be interesting to get known where this bug appeared between versions 9.0 and 12.1.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thank you. The error communication appears on my comp in approximately two minutes (`AbsoluteTiming` does not work here for me.).

Comment: For me it returns 1/2 with no errors or messages after about three minutes. My $Version is 12.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (April 7, 2019).

Comment: @TedErsek: Thank you. It's kind of you.

Comment: With v12.2 on a Mac and using `AbsoluteTiming` I obtained `{101.674, 1/2}`

Comment: @BobHanlon: Thank you. Nice to hear it.

Comment: (1) This is unlikely to be OS specific. (2) In general nature it is also unlikely to be version specific. That is to say, this type of issue might appear in many versions, although small code changes might make it more or less likely to manifest for this particular example. (3) If I can make it appear in a debugging kernel it will get fixed.

Comment: Very interesting—this error appeared for me, but *only after* I switched languages to Ukrainian.

Comment: Tried a couple other languages: I was able to reproduce the bug in Vietnamese and Portuguese, but not English, Spanish, or Russian. Weird. Does this narrow down where it's occurring, though, @DanielLichtblau ?

Comment: I do not see why it would depend on language. I should mention that the appearance of the `iCopyExpr()` in that note is not necessarily indicative of the underlying bug. It might be a symptom of downstream damage and, as such, could perhaps be OS dependent.

Comment: (1) I had no success in reproducing this in either a debugging or a regular kernel. Try setting ``Internal`Integrate`debugSwitch=10`` and rerunning. This will give a slew of printout. If it crashes, I'd want to see what is printed shortly before the crash. (2) I do not advertise this flag. Try not to make me regret having mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be fixed in 12.3.1. No internal error messages. On windows 10, from clean kernel:

[image]

```
Integrate[
 UnitBox[(x + y)/eps - eps/3]/eps*UnitBox[(z + y)/eps]/eps*
  UnitBox[(x + z)/eps]/eps, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 Assumptions -> eps > 0 && eps < 1/2]
```

gives

```
1/2
```

**edit**

Info requested by comment:

```
AssociationMap[
 SystemInformation[#, "ReleaseID"] &, {"Kernel", "FrontEnd"}]
```

gives

```
<|"Kernel" -> "12.3.1.0 (7342483, 202106198367)", 
 "FrontEnd" -> "12.3.1.0 (7342483, 202106194031)"|>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the release id of your installation of `12.3.1` by running, `AssociationMap[
 SystemInformation[#, "ReleaseID"] &, {"Kernel", "FrontEnd"}]`.

Comment: @user13892 fyi, added.

Comment: In the front end when you press `Ctrl+F` to open the `Find and Replace` dialog box, does it render properly for you?

Comment: @user13892  Yes. Ctrl+F worked fine. got the dialog box and renders just fine.

Comment: Sorry to bother you so much. Can you check what version of `MXNet` your `12.3.1` is using by running, `Needs["MXNetLink\`"]; GetMXNetVersion[]`. I think I got some corrupted version of `12.3.1` with many bugs.

Comment: @user13892  it says  `10600` on windows 10.

Comment: One last thing what windows version are you on? I am on `Version 20H2 (OS Build 19042.1052)`. Also does your front end also sees the correct version of windows by running, `SystemInformation["FrontEnd","OperatingSystemVersion"]`?

Comment: @user13892  it says `10.0 (Build 19041)`